# BigQuery JOIN on two tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run the following query but keep on encountering the same error

> Query Failed
>   Error: Encountered "" at line 6, column 33. Was expecting one of:

The query is:

> SELECT 1_0_MEMBER_GROUP.User_Group,
>   
>        1_0_MEMBER_GROUP.Member_ID,
>   
>        1_4_MEMBER_TRAN_YEAR.MEMBER_UID 
>   
> FROM [Dataset1.1_0_MEMBER_GROUP] 
>   
> JOIN [Dataset1.1_4_MEMBER_TRAN_YEAR] 
>   
> ON 1_0_MEMBER_GROUP.Member_ID = 1_4_MEMBER_TRAN_YEAR.MEMBER_UID

I can't work out why it won't run and must be over looking something very simple.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should use a table alias. Try

```
SELECT member_group.User_Group, 
member_group.Member_ID, 
member_tran_year.MEMBER_UID 
FROM [Dataset1.1_0_MEMBER_GROUP] as member_group
JOIN [Dataset1.1_4_MEMBER_TRAN_YEAR] as member_tran_year
ON member_group.Member_ID = member_tran_year.MEMBER_UID
```