# BigQuery Table Joins (Fields with Hyphen Values)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When joining tables in BigQuery on a field with hyphen values (e.g. field is 'product_id' and the ids have values such as 'mcmaster-1000'), do you need enclose it in special chars if it's already a STRING type field in both tables?

Edit: @Gordon, apologies for that -- still a novice when it comes to flagging posts on here.

@Mikhail, I'm working on a project for a client where I'm joining line order items and ad data based on product ids. I'm troubleshooting some discrepancies we're seeing and I'm wondering if the hyphens in the ids are posing an issue. I know that case sensitivity was an issue and I had to use LOWER when joining on those ids in the past.

Comment: Enclose what in special characters?

Comment: If you mean backticks, that's only needed when the table or column *name* contains special characters. The values are irrelevant.

Comment: An answer for MySQL is not an appropriate duplicate for a BigQuery question.

Comment: what makes you ask this question? are you experiencing some issue? share more details so we will be able to help rather than answering trivial `"No, you do not need  to do so"`

Answer (score 0):

As Mikhail mentioned, there is no need to enclose fields with any special characters and the hyphens in the ids are not posing an issue.

For more details about the operators and regulations for joining tables please refer to [1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax)  (for Standard SQL Query Syntax)
and the answer provided in [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475033/bigquery-join-on-two-tables).